# How to split installer data into multiple smaller parts?

Tags: installation, dvd, installer, dvd-burning, nero

For example, I have an installer package like this:

```
Setup.exe - 4MB
Setup-1.bin - 8GB
```

So I want to split the file Setup-1.bin into

```
Setup-1.bin - 4GB
Setup-2.bin - 4GB
```

The purpose is to have 2 DVDs like this:

DVD #1

```
Setup.exe - 4MB
Setup-1.bin - 4GB
```

DVD #2

```
Setup.exe - 4MB
Setup-2.bin - 4GB
```

So when I install in the future, I just insert disc 1, then after disc 1 is done, it asks to insert disc 2.

So how to split installer data (Setup-1.bin) into multiple smaller parts (Setup-1.bin & Setup-2.bin)?

Trivial: I'm using nero to burn disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a generic, non-scriptable or intelligent installer, you cant.  If an installer is hard coded to look for a file in a relative path, that complete file has to be where it expects it to be, or it will fail.  In addition to that, you cant just split a file and expect the installer to understand the file has been modified or that it should even look for another file.  It could very well be the .bin file is compressed and you wouldnt be able to uncompress it without the file being complete.

You could make an self decompressing archive and split it amongst as many discs as you want.  You could then copy the contents to the computer and execute it, or execute it from disc.  Then run the installer and delete the files when done.